# How can I get black axes, but also a (default) grey grid in a pyqtgraph diagram?

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyqtgraph

I'm trying to change the color of the axes of a pyqtgraph diagram to black, but if I use `self.graphWidget.getAxis('bottom').setPen('k')` the grid is also black and I would like to have it in default grey. I didn't find any solution. Is there a way to achieve this and additionally color the tick numbers black?

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
import pyqtgraph as pg

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.plot()

    def plot(self):
        self.graphWidget = pg.PlotWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.graphWidget)
        self.graphWidget.setBackground('w')
        pen = pg.mkPen(color=('b'), width=2)

        styles = {'color':'r', 'font-size':'15px'}


        self.graphWidget.setLabel('left', 'x-values', **styles)
        self.graphWidget.setLabel('bottom', 'y-values', **styles)
        self.graphWidget.showGrid(x=True, y=True)

        self.graphWidget.getAxis('bottom').setPen('k')
        self.graphWidget.getAxis('left').setPen('k')

        x_values = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
        y_values = [2, 1, 2, 4, 3]

        self.graphWidget.plot(x_values, y_values, pen=pen, symbol='o',
                                   symbolSize=8, symbolPen='k', symbolBrush='k')

def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = MainWindow()
    main.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I'm using Python 3.8, PyQt5 5.15.0, PyCharm 2020.2 and Linux Mint 19.3.

Comment: Also searching for an answer to this, did you ever find anything?

Answer (score 0):

PyqtGraph uses default pen to draw all lines, ticks and grid in AxisItem. That's why it draws everything in the same color. Changing tick text color is easy, You can use `textPen` attribute for `pg.AxisItem`. Or set textPen for already created axis with  `self.graphWidget.getAxis('bottom').setTextPen(black_pen)`.

To make axis line in specific color, we must re-implement `drawPicture` method of `pg.AxisItem`. We can introduce new init parameter called `axisPen`, which will be used only for axis line.

Here is full working code:

```
import sys

from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
import pyqtgraph as pg
from pyqtgraph import debug as debug


class ColoredAxis(pg.AxisItem):

    def __init__(self, orientation, pen=None, textPen=None, axisPen=None, linkView=None, parent=None,
                 maxTickLength=-5, showValues=True, text='', units='', unitPrefix='', **args):
        super().__init__(orientation, pen=pen, textPen=textPen, linkView=linkView, parent=parent,
                         maxTickLength=maxTickLength,
                         showValues=showValues, text=text, units=units, unitPrefix=unitPrefix, **args)
        self.axisPen = axisPen
        if self.axisPen is None:
            self.axisPen = self.pen()

    def drawPicture(self, p, axisSpec, tickSpecs, textSpecs):
        profiler = debug.Profiler()

        p.setRenderHint(p.RenderHint.Antialiasing, False)
        p.setRenderHint(p.RenderHint.TextAntialiasing, True)

        ## draw long line along axis
        pen, p1, p2 = axisSpec
        # Use axis pen to draw axis line
        p.setPen(self.axisPen)
        p.drawLine(p1, p2)
        # Switch back to normal pen
        p.setPen(pen)
        # p.translate(0.5,0)  ## resolves some damn pixel ambiguity

        ## draw ticks
        for pen, p1, p2 in tickSpecs:
            p.setPen(pen)
            p.drawLine(p1, p2)
        profiler('draw ticks')

        # Draw all text
        if self.style['tickFont'] is not None:
            p.setFont(self.style['tickFont'])
        p.setPen(self.textPen())
        bounding = self.boundingRect().toAlignedRect()
        p.setClipRect(bounding)
        for rect, flags, text in textSpecs:
            p.drawText(rect, int(flags), text)

        profiler('draw text')


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.plot()

    def plot(self):
        black_pen = pg.mkPen(color='black', width=2)
        self.axis_x = ColoredAxis(orientation='bottom', axisPen=black_pen)
        self.axis_y = ColoredAxis(orientation='left', axisPen=black_pen)
        self.graphWidget = pg.PlotWidget(background="w", axisItems={'bottom': self.axis_x, 'left': self.axis_y})
        self.setCentralWidget(self.graphWidget)

        styles = {'color': 'b', 'font-size': '15px'}

        self.graphWidget.setLabel('left', 'x-values', **styles)
        self.graphWidget.setLabel('bottom', 'y-values', **styles)
        self.graphWidget.showGrid(x=True, y=True)

        x_values = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
        y_values = [2, 1, 2, 4, 3]

        pen = pg.mkPen(color='b', width=2)
        self.graphWidget.plot(x_values, y_values, pen=pen, symbol='o',
                              symbolSize=8, symbolPen='k', symbolBrush='k')

        self.axis_x.setTextPen(black_pen)
        self.axis_y.setTextPen(black_pen)


def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = MainWindow()
    main.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```